# Not able to import custom package

Tags: python, module, pip, package, file-handling

### what I am doing.

- I am building a python package.
- file hirarchy of the package is as following.

```
package/
    library1/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2 py
    setup.py
    LICENCE
    README.md
```

- due to some reason I need to import module2 in module1
- I have described packages in setup.py as follows.
  `setup`(
  `name = "package"`,
  `packages = [ "library1", "library2"]`)

### once I have built the package I installed it to my device.

- I tried to import `package`
- but I received an error no module named `package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can install your package w/o building it first:

   `pip install package --editable`

   It stays where it is and you can continue editing/debugging.
2. Your *package* is added to the Python sys.path, so Python looks inside *package* for imports but can't import *package* itself.
3. You import module2 via

   `import library1.module2`

   This is an absolute import, so it works from everywhere.